# How to extract some mathematical expressionfrom pdf using python?

Tags: python, pdf, export-to-csv, mathematical-expressions, python-pdfreader

I have a pdf  which has math equations like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KWgI.jpg)

I am trying to extract the objective questions from a pdf file and convert them into csv file using python in such a way that each row of table contain a question, four options in each column and a correct option (so total six columns). But that pdf also have those  mathematical equations which I can't write them into csv file as they are . Is it possible to write those equations in my csv file as they are in pdf file ?

Comment: Is the pdf made from latex?

Comment: I don't know i downloaded it from internet

Comment: Try using pylatex. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pylatex-module-in-python/ would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how the formula is represented in PDF. It can be either XObject, inline image or unicode text.

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/). It can extract plain texts, texts containing PDF commands and images from PDF documents.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""
images = []
try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        images.extend(viewer.canvas.inline_images)
        images.extend(viewer.canvas.images.values())
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```